# Excel chart show only limited labels on x-axis

Tags: excel

I have an excel chart with daily points for a year. As you can imagine it can become crowded. I want to show only 3 points start-date, some date in the middle and last-date.

If I got to format axis -> axis options -> Labels -> Internal between labels -> Specific interval unit = 180 (default it Automatic), I don't necessarily get the last date. I played around with 30/60/90 but its all random trail error.
Is there a way to show x-axis with 3 points: start, middle (does not have to be exact middle) and end?

Comment: Try defining the x-axis labels using a set range of cells. when you click on the axis in the chart, the x-axis range is the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

[image]

Column c contains a 1 if you want that label on the x-axis, column d the if() to put the x-axis value from Col A or a blank.

Add, or remove labels as needed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Solar Mike, neat trick, I can surely use in future... I forgot to mention that in my case I was drawing chart from a pivot (and date range may change per user filter and i want to avoid additional logic in each of my pivot)