# Excel VBA Macro Show / Hide Chart Title

Tags: excel, vba, charts, title

Trying to hide Chart Title:

```
With objChart.Chart
        .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False '1
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered '2
        .SetSourceData Source:=myDataRange '3
        .HasLegend = False '4
        .HasTitle = False '5
        '.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone) '6
```

Tried both (lines 5 and 6), neither work.
Line 6 is from the recorded Macro.
Any other way to do this?
(`.HasLegend` works as expected)

Comment: I would source the chart title from a cell and use if() to let the cell show title or blank - no need for vba.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919797/4961700

Comment: Oh, ok. Yeah, that would work. But I'd like to do this in vba, as long as it's somehow possible.

Comment: So I disabled this line: `.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("B1") ' SET`, which points to the cell with the title. This way, the Chart Title doesn't appear. But then, the Series has no automatically set name. Is there a way to have both? Series Name yes, Chart Title no?

Comment: Series name and chart title are different things though?  Are you only asking about the chart title?

Comment: Yes, the Chart Title. I want to hide it. And with the code I have, `.HasTitle = False` as well as `.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)` don't work, as long as `.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("B1") ` is "turned on/enabled". And yes, as far as I understand, these are two different things. So why does this happen? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart 'for example
    
'adds title
cht.HasTitle = True
cht.chartTitle.Text = "TitleHere"
    
'removes title
cht.HasTitle = False
```